# How to refer to class properties in XML docs C#?

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

Suppose I have a method in a class

```
public class MyClass{
   public int MyInt;

   /// <summary>
   /// Prints out the value of <paramref name="MyInt">
   /// </summary>
   public void PrintValueOfMyInt()
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

Is this the correct way to refer to the `MyInt` member in the XML doc above `PrintValueOfMyInt`? If not, how to do it?

Comment: Use `<see>`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags#see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to use `<see cref="MyInt"/>`, so in total we get:

```
/// <summary>
/// Prints out the value of <see cref="MyInt"/>
/// </summary>
public void PrintValueOfMyInt()
{
  ...
}
```